# Finding standard deviation of $X$ where probability is $kp$

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be a random variable which takes values $k$ with the probability $kp$, where $k=1,2,3,4$ and $p\in (0,1)$. Then the standard deviation of $X$ is

$\sum p_i=1\implies p=\frac1{10}$. So, the mean ($\mu$) is $3$ by using the formula $\sum x_ip_i$.

To calculate variance, I can use either $\sum (x_i-\mu)^2p_i$ or $\sum x_i^2p_i-\mu^2$. From the former, I am getting the variance as $1$, from the latter, I am getting $-8$. I think I am doing something wrong, don't know what.

Comment: You'll have to edit in *how* those formulae get you respectively $1,\,-8$, or we can't see your error; all we can do is show the correct calculations.

Comment: ok, sure, will add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first formula gives $(-2)^2\frac{1}{10}+(-1)^2\frac{2}{10}+1^2\frac{4}{10}=1$. The second gives $\frac{1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3}{10}-3^2=10-9=1$.

---

A generalization:

Suppose $X$ has support $1,\,\cdots,\,n$, with $P\left(X=k\right)=\frac{2k}{n\left(n+1\right)}$. Then $\mu=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k^{2}}{n\left(n+1\right)}=\frac{2n+1}{3}$ and$$\begin{align}\sigma^{2}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(k-\frac{2n+1}{3}\right)^{2}\frac{2k}{n\left(n+1\right)}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k^{3}-\frac{8n+4}{3}k^{2}+\frac{2\left(2n+1\right)^{2}}{9}k}{n\left(n+1\right)}\\&=\frac{1}{2}n\left(n+1\right)-\frac{1}{9}\left(2n+1\right)^{2}\\&=\frac{\left(n-1\right)\left(n+2\right)}{18}.\end{align}$$We get the same result with$$\sigma^{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k^{3}}{n\left(n+1\right)}-\frac{\left(2n+1\right)^{2}}{9}=\frac{1}{2}n\left(n+1\right)-\frac{\left(2n+1\right)^{2}}{9}.$$

Comment: My mistake was that I was squaring $10$ as well.